# Efficient way of matching a subtree, using cypher in Neo4J?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

If I have a tree modelled in Neo4J, and I know all the indexed node properties of a possible subtree, how can I quickly do a match to confirm if that subtree exists?

For an easy to understand example, if my tree is a representation of all the directories and files on a disk, and what I want to confirm is the existence of a file, here's what I'm doing now to test if /a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/j/k/file.txt exists in a graph where my filesystem nodes have label `mylabel` and have an indexed basename property:

```
MATCH (root:`mylabel` { basename: '/' })-[:contains]->(`1`:`mylabel` { basename: 'a' })-[:contains]->(`2`:`mylabel` { basename: 'b' })-[:contains]->(`3`:`mylabel` { basename: 'c' })-[:contains]->(`4`:`mylabel` { basename: 'd' })-[:contains]->(`5`:`mylabel` { basename: 'e' })-[:contains]->(`6`:`mylabel` { basename: 'f' })-[:contains]->(`7`:`mylabel` { basename: 'g' })-[:contains]->(`8`:`mylabel ` { basename: 'h' })-[:contains]->(`9`:`mylabel ` { basename: 'i' })-[:contains]->(`10`:`mylabel` { basename: 'j' })-[:contains]->(`11`:`mylabel` { basename: 'k' })-[:contains]->(leaf:`vdp`:`mylabel` { basename: 'file.txt' }) RETURN leaf
```

I also happen to have an absolute path property on the leaf node, but I can't just search for that because I want to use a similar query to do a merge if I'm adding a file, and in case the file has moved (by deleting the relationship of leaf to k, and adding a new relationship of leaf to some other directory node) without the path property getting updated. Also, I can have the same absolute path multiple times for different files, because it can be for different disks (this is modelled by the root node having a basename that includes the disk name, but that isn't seen in the leaf nodes path property).

The above query takes 2-7 seconds to run (uncached). Is there any way to do something like this quicker? When I specify every node in the path I hoped Neo4J could cope even with paths of length 12+.

Answer (score 2):

Some ideas here:

- since you always start at the root node (and I assume there is only one) you don't really need indexes here. Instead assign the root node a label, e.g. `Root` and make sure it's the only node carrying that label
- With that in place you can hint Cypher my matching the root node first and do the path matching after a with
- I assume everything in a subfolder in your hierarchy has the `mylabel` label, so performance wise it's better to skip the check (since it's implicitly given)

.

```
MATCH (r:Root)
WITH r
MATCH (r)-[:contains]->(a { basename: 'a' })
-[:contains]->( { basename: 'b' })
-[:contains]->( { basename: 'c' })
-[:contains]->( { basename: 'd' })
-[:contains]->( { basename: 'e' })
-[:contains]->( { basename: 'f' })
-[:contains]->( { basename: 'g' })
-[:contains]->( { basename: 'h' })
-[:contains]->( { basename: 'i' })
-[:contains]->( { basename: 'j' })
-[:contains]->( { basename: 'k' })
-[:contains]->(leaf:`vdp`:`mylabel` { basename: 'file.txt' }) 
RETURN leaf
```

In case you don't know the depth of your leaf beforehand you can use variable path length matchers:

```
match (r:Root)
with r
match p=(r)-[:contains*]->()
with p,[x in tail(nodes(p))|x.basename] as names
where names= ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","file.txt"]
return p, names
```

However this statement will fully traverse your while directory tree and does not an early skip approach. You can do that by using e.g. in Java using traversal API.

Comment: I have multiple roots (one for each disc). In any case, even if I match on root node id and use with, it doesn't make any difference to speed.

Comment: I tried without all the labels, but it's hard to tell if it helped much. I don't think so. Is there a way to force Neo4J to not use any cache? Difficult to test things otherwise.

Comment: can you share your graph.db folder? Regarding caches see my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31579763/how-to-compare-performance-on-neo4j-queries-without-cache.